# Programming GPU to control DVI output

Tags: video, gpu

I have a NVIDIA GeForce 8400GS graphics card which has a DVI output and I would like to take a video or series of frames and display them as the DVI output for WUXGA (1,920 × 1,200) @ 120 Hz with GTF (2 x 154 MHz), which is a possible display mode for DVI according to the wikipedia article. I want to do this because I want a high frame rate display that is higher than a video file.

Can you give me some resources where I can learn how to control the DVI output in this way? Otherwise can you give me other ideas for achieving this framerate for a display?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you switch to that mode using ChangeDisplaySettingsEx? If so, it should be fairly straightforward from there.

Comment: Well if I plug in a 120Hz display device, will it detect that setting automatically? I want to take a 120Hz display device and use it to display a video or series of frames at 120Hz. I don't know about 120Hz video files or how I would do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into NVidia NVAPI.